# Created my first wordpress plugin template page, need comments

Tags: php

I managed to create my first wordpress plugin template page collecting various code snippets to make the page function.

Everything works fine, but I need hear comments from PHP & wordpress experts to see if it's well-coded.

Here's the code.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: name
Plugin URI: http://www.example.com
Description: desc
Version: 1
Author: someone
Author URI: http://www.example
*/
?>
<?php
function my_first_plugin_init(){
    register_setting( 'my_first_plugin_grp', 'my_first_plugin' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_first_plugin_init' );

function my_first_plugin_add_page() {
    add_menu_page('plugin title', 'plugin title', 'manage_options', 'my_first_plugin', 'my_first_plugin_do_page' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_first_plugin_add_page' );

function my_first_plugin_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
    wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
    wp_enqueue_script('my-upload', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'/upload-func.js');
}
add_action('admin_print_scripts', 'my_first_plugin_scripts');

function my_first_plugin_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('ads-stls', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'/ads-options.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
}
add_action('admin_print_styles', 'my_first_plugin_styles');

function my_first_plugin_do_page() {
    global $select_options, $radio_options;
    if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['settings-updated'] ) )
    $_REQUEST['settings-updated'] = false;
?>
<div class="wrap">
    <h2><?php echo $plgnme; ?></h2>
    <?php if ( false !== $_REQUEST['settings-updated'] ) : ?>
    <div class="updated fade"><p><strong>Options saved.</strong></p></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields( 'my_first_plugin_grp' ); ?>
    <?php $options = get_option( 'my_first_plugin' ); ?>    
<!-- content start -->
<!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
Sample text input:
<input id="my_first_plugin[lpgrdneurl]" class="regular-text" type="text" name="my_first_plugin[lpgrdneurl]" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $options[$lpgrdneurl] ); ?>" placeholder="http://" />
<!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
<!-- content end -->
    <?php submit_button(); ?>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your plugin is not translation ready, see [`l18n`](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers). In the plugin header, you should add

```
* Text Domain: your-textdomain
* Domain Path: /languages
```

Create the language files in `wp-content/plugins/your-plugin/languages` with [PoEdit](http://www.poedit.net/). And make all relevant strings translatable with:

```
add_menu_page( __('Plugin title','your-textdomain'), ...
// and
<?php _e('Options saved','your-textdomain'); ?>
```

---

There's a big issue: you're printing your styles and scripts all over the admin area. **It's essential** that you always target the correct page.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_first_plugin_add_page' );
function my_first_plugin_add_page() 
{
    $hook = add_menu_page(
        'plugin title', 
        'plugin title', 
        'manage_options', 
        'my_first_plugin', 
        'my_first_plugin_do_page'
    );
    add_action( "admin_print_scripts-$hook", 'my_first_plugin_scripts' );   
}
```

---

You don't need to close and open PHP tags if you're not swapping between PHP and HTML:

```
*/
?>
<?php
function my_first_plugin_init(){
```

Get rid of the very last `?>` too.
See [Why do some scripts omit the closing php tag `?>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3219383/1287812).

---

It's easier to have a general picture if you declare first the hooks and then the callbacks.

```
add_action('first_hook', 'prefix_first_callback');
add_action('second_hook', 'prefix_second_callback');
add_filter('third_hook', 'prefix_third_callback');
function prefix_first_callback() {}
function prefix_second_callback() {}
function prefix_third_callback() {}
```

---

It's important to prefix everything, function names, meta data and `$_POST`ed data. But for function names this quickly turns into hard to read code. Encapsulating everything in a class avoids this. And also allows us to start-up our plugin in a safe point: `plugins_loaded`, see [Best way to initiate a class in a WP plugin?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/70055/12615).

The following is a clean version of [Plugin Class Demo](https://gist.github.com/toscho/3804204), by [toscho◆](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/73/toscho). Please, go to the source for the full documented class.

```
add_action(
    'plugins_loaded',
    array ( PREFIX_My_Plugin::get_instance(), 'plugin_setup' )
);

class PREFIX_My_Plugin
{
    protected static $instance = NULL;
    public $plugin_url = '';
    public $plugin_path = '';

    public static function get_instance()
    {
        NULL === self::$instance and self::$instance = new self;
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function plugin_setup()
    {
        $this->plugin_url    = plugins_url( '/', __FILE__ );
        $this->plugin_path   = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
        $this->load_language( 'plugin_unique_name' );
        // Your stuff: register actions and filters
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, '_admin_init' ) );
    }

    public function _admin_init()
    {
        // your_stuff();
    }

    public function __construct() {}

    public function load_language( $domain )
    {
        load_plugin_textdomain(
            $domain,
            FALSE,
            $this->plugin_path . 'languages'
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the site!

The most difficult part you done; that's to create something. I know a lot of people with tons of ideas, but none of them come to reality. So, well done for your first step.

About your plugin, it's a very simple one. I believe everyone here would do in a different way. The best practices you will get them during your learning journey and time. However, I would suggest you to use (and learn from it) a plugin boilerplate as base. There are several out there, but the follow one is quite popular. https://github.com/tommcfarlin/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate

I would say study that plugin and *port* yours to it. It's a nice way to learn new things. And if you don't know OOP, don't worry. Just because you see some code using class, it doesn't mean that they are *real* OOP. But learning the basic of PHP OOP is a great thing.

**Reviewing the code**

Two small things:

- To enqueue scripts AND styles use `wp_enqueue_scripts` for the front-end. And `admin_enqueue_scripts` for the back-end. http://make.wordpress.org/core/2011/12/12/use-wp_enqueue_scripts-not-wp_print_styles-to-enqueue-scripts-and-styles-for-the-frontend/
- Do not use the close `?>`php tag in the end of the file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410704/why-would-one-omit-the-close-tag

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I forgot to mention that i'm not a php coder. So I just collected some code snippets to make a basic reliable plugin with just simple form options.

Comment: One more reason for you to use a plugin starter/boilerplate.

Comment: you didn't really review the code

Comment: Update my answer.